# HTML Email <img> not working

Tags: html, html-email

I've taken over a project that is using htmlmimemail to send html emails.

Below is the source of the email:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<p><img src="https://VALID.IMAGE.LINK" alt=""></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Dear test,</p>
<p>This is the body</p>
```

The above image is not displaying however, when viewed in outlook/browser/webmail.

Is there something I'm missing? This looks like a valid html email.

The image src has been tested in a browser and it works.

EDIT---

When clicking on download images in my email client, the image still does not work, looks like below.

[image]

Comment: I think most e-mail clients no longer automatically download images, to protect users from mail tracking scripts etc.  Are you sure the mail client you are using to test this does not offer the option to download images?

Comment: @HaukurHaf There is a download images button on the email, I've updated my question to show what the email looks like after I do that.

Comment: what is the extension/format on the image. Some mail clients will not accept certain formats. The safest formats to use are .gif and .jpg.

Comment: Also, if you are on a corporate network, check to make sure the image is hosted to be viewed by all and not displayed only to those on network. This might be causing issues as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image was coming from a site that did not have a valid SSL certificate. It seems email does not like to load images where the SSL certificate for the domain is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Email clients tend to block remote images as a security feature.

You will have to embed the image into the email to be sure it loads - sorry, but I'm on my phone so can't prove links readily

Answer (score -2):

What version of Outlook?  At a certain point Outlook stopped loading 3rd party graphics links by default, and only loads them when the user specifically clicks in the upper margin to allow images to load.  Depending on your site setup (eg. what your IT department sets permissions) you may not even be able to allow it to load outside images.

One thing to try is adding the domain your image is located in to your trusted domain list in the IE settings.  (Most MS products tend to know about and obey the rules for IE when dealing with internet content.)